# Unable to install any npm package on Windows 7 connected to Internet via wifi

Tags: node.js, plugins, npm, npm-install, econnrefused

I am unable to install any npm package like browser-sync, gulp, grunt on my Windows 7 . I am trying to install with Admin user.  I connect to net using Wifi(Netgear) where my broadband is a dial-up connection (ADSL). I have not setup any proxy config.please find the log below.

```
C:\>npm install -g browser-sync
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "browser-sync"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1077:14)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080]
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   address: '127.0.0.1',
npm ERR!   port: 8080 }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

I am unable to install any npm package like browser-sync.Could you please suggest how to fix this error.

I have already tried set registry to http://registry.npmjs.org/. Could you please suggest how to fix this error. I have already tried running the command "npm install connect" as Administrator and got the same thing. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Can you also paste output of `npm config ls -l`.

Comment: Hi @nash_ag, plz find the log in https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8490

Comment: Hi @nash_ag, i have set proxy after i got the same error, I used to get same error earlier also.  But to overcome that, I have set it to my localhost.Request your kind help in fixing this problem .

Comment: `proxy` config should not be set to `localhost:8080`. Can you delete, also if you are behind a firewall - that can be cause of this issue.

Comment: @nash_ag Thanks a ton !! I have deleted the entries for proxies in .npmrc file. Now it worked like a magic ! and also i am not using any firewall . Once again many thanks !